# how to create-react-app without npm -g install

Tags: reactjs, npm

> core-js@2.6.9 postinstall C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\appreact\my-app\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
>   node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
>
> core-js-pure@3.1.4 postinstall C:\Users\Pc\Desktop\appreact\my-app\node_modules\core-js-pure
>   node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

- react@16.8.6
- react-dom@16.8.6
- react-scripts@3.0.1
  added 1388 packages from 675 contributors and audited 902283 packages in 370.144s
  found 0 vulnerabilities

what's the problem plz i can't create my appp react ???

Comment: Can you explain what you've posted and what you're trying to accomplish? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your title and your post seem entirely unrelated, so to answer the question from your title (because the post doesn't actually have one): if you want to run `create-react-app` (or any other node binary) without globally installing it, then you can use [npx](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npx).

(npx is the only package that you should always have installed globally, because it lets you directly invoke local node binaries)

Install the tool you need locally using the standard npm install command, in this case `npm install create-react-app` (without a `-g` flag), and then run it using npx, in this particular case by calling `npx create-react-app`.

Answer (score 0):

try `npx create-react-app <your app´s name>` but you need to have npm installed